# DVWA Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: mysql

I get the following error when I click the create/reset database for DVWA:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
C:\MySQL\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\DBMS\MySQL.php:9 Stack trace: #0 
C:\MySQL\htdocs\dvwa\setup.php(17): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\MySQL\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\DBMS\MySQL.php on line 9
```

Comment: Are you using PHP7? There is no `mysql_` database extension anymore is PHP7. It has been removed after being deprecated for many years.

Comment: I used XAMPP to install PHP.

Comment: `C:\MySQL\htdocs\` thats a very odd place to have an htdocs folder

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was using it just for MySQL then I changed it and also version 3.2.2

Comment: You will have to install an older version of XAMPP that comes with PHP5.6